# Tomar más de una sola foto en aplicación web con android o ios

Tags: html, android, django, ios, imagen

Cree un portal web usando `html`,`django` y `jquery` de manera que sea `responsive` ya que ciertas funciones requieren de que el usuario ingrese desde su teléfono celular o tableta y tomar fotos con esta para poderlas mandar a un servidor, para lograr esto utilizo un campo `<input type="file" id="file" name="file" accept="image/*" multiple>`. Al seleccionar el campo con estos dispositivos me da la opción de tomar foto desde el dispositivo y subirla o seleccionar las imagenes ya guardadas en el dispositivo y subirlas, cuando las selecciono puedo hacerlo con muchas a la vez, pero al seleccionar la opción de tomar foto solo me permite hacerlo con una ¿Cómo puedo dar la opción de permitir tomar varias fotos y subirlas todas en ese momento?

De ante mano, gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: La verdad no he visto antes un comportamiento así, ni en una app nativa y menos de web. Sería un comportamiento interesante, pero cuentas con una limitante, y es que mientras sea web no es una alternativa que puedas tener y modificar porque dependerá del navegador el comportamiento de los archivos y la forma cómo estos son seleccionados

Comment: he trabajado con Ionic y django mediante celery he mandado mis fotos. Como deseas muchas fotos, debes usar inlines para almacenar dichas fotos.

Comment: Gracias @JeanpierreRivas investigaré al respecto